I am scanning for devices in my Android app, but iOS devices are not being detected
interface BluetoothDeviceCallback {
    fun onDeviceFound(device: BluetoothDevice, rssi: Int)
}
interface BluetoothConnectionCallback {
    fun onConnectionStateChanged(connected: Boolean)
}

class BluetoothService : Service() {

    private val binder = BluetoothBinder()
    private lateinit var bluetoothAdapter: BluetoothAdapter
    private val scannedDevices = mutableMapOf<String, BluetoothDevice>()
    private var bluetoothLeScanner: BluetoothLeScanner? = null
    private var bluetoothGatt: BluetoothGatt? = null
    private var deviceCallback: BluetoothDeviceCallback? = null
    private var connectionCallback: BluetoothConnectionCallback? = null

    fun getBluetoothDeviceByAddress(address: String): BluetoothDevice? {
        return scannedDevices[address]
    }

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        val bluetoothManager = getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE) as BluetoothManager
        bluetoothAdapter = bluetoothManager.adapter
        bluetoothLeScanner = bluetoothAdapter.bluetoothLeScanner

        startForegroundService()
    }

    fun setDeviceCallback(callback: BluetoothDeviceCallback) {
        this.deviceCallback = callback
    }

    fun setConnectionCallback(callback: BluetoothConnectionCallback) {
        this.connectionCallback = callback
    }

    private fun startForegroundService() {
        val channelId = "BluetoothServiceChannel"
        val channelName = "Bluetooth Service"
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            val channel = NotificationChannel(channelId, channelName, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT)
            val manager = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
            manager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
        }

        val notificationIntent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
        val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE)

        val notification: Notification = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId)
            .setContentTitle("Bluetooth Service")
            .setContentText("Bluetooth connection is active")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .build()

        startForeground(1, notification)
    }

    fun startScan() {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                this,
                Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN
            ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        ) {
            Log.e("BluetoothService", "Bluetooth scan permission not granted")
            return
        }

        val scanSettings = ScanSettings.Builder()
            .setScanMode(ScanSettings.SCAN_MODE_LOW_LATENCY)
            .build()

        // 필터 없이 스캔 시작
        bluetoothLeScanner?.startScan(null, scanSettings, leScanCallback)

        Log.d("BluetoothService", "Bluetooth scanning started")
    }

    fun stopScan() {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                this,
                Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN
            ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        ) {
            Log.e("BluetoothService", "Bluetooth scan permission not granted")
            return
        }

        bluetoothLeScanner?.stopScan(leScanCallback)
        Log.d("BluetoothService", "Bluetooth scanning stopped")
    }

    private val leScanCallback = object : ScanCallback() {
        override fun onScanResult(callbackType: Int, result: ScanResult) {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                    applicationContext,
                    Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT
                ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            ) {
                Log.e("BluetoothService", "Bluetooth connect permission not granted")
                return
            }

            super.onScanResult(callbackType, result)
            val device = result.device
            val rssi = result.rssi

            // 모든 장치가 검색되도록 허용
            Log.d("BluetoothService", "Device found: ${device.name} - ${device.address}")

            // 콜백으로 검색된 장치를 전달
            deviceCallback?.onDeviceFound(device, rssi)
        }

        override fun onScanFailed(errorCode: Int) {
            super.onScanFailed(errorCode)
            Log.e("BluetoothService", "Bluetooth scan failed with error code: $errorCode")
        }
    }

    fun connectToDevice(device: BluetoothDevice) {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                this,
                Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT
            ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        ) {
            Log.e("BluetoothService", "Bluetooth connect permission not granted")
            return
        }
        bluetoothGatt = device.connectGatt(this, false, gattCallback)
    }

    private val gattCallback = object : BluetoothGattCallback() {
        override fun onConnectionStateChange(gatt: BluetoothGatt?, status: Int, newState: Int) {
            super.onConnectionStateChange(gatt, status, newState)
            if (newState == BluetoothGatt.STATE_CONNECTED) {
                Log.d("BluetoothService", "Connected to GATT server.")
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                        applicationContext,
                        Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT
                    ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                ) {
                    Log.e("BluetoothService", "Bluetooth connect permission not granted")
                    return
                }
                bluetoothGatt?.discoverServices()
                connectionCallback?.onConnectionStateChanged(true)
            } else if (newState == BluetoothGatt.STATE_DISCONNECTED) {
                Log.d("BluetoothService", "Disconnected from GATT server.")
                connectionCallback?.onConnectionStateChanged(false)
            }
        }

        // Other callback methods such as onServicesDiscovered, onCharacteristicRead, etc.
    }

    override fun onBind(intent: Intent?): IBinder {
        return binder
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                this,
                Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT
            ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        ) {
            Log.e("BluetoothService", "Bluetooth connect permission not granted")
            return
        }
        bluetoothGatt?.close()
    }

    inner class BluetoothBinder : Binder() {
        fun getService(): BluetoothService = this@BluetoothService
    }
}

I am performing a Bluetooth scan but cannot detect iOS devices with a company ID of 004C. When I set the company ID of the Bluetooth device to 0000, it is detected, but when I change it to 004C, it is not detected. I confirmed that the device is detected with the 004C company ID when using the nrfConnect app with the nofilter option. What steps should I take in my code to scan for iOS devices?
I hope to scan iOS Bluetooth devices using the Android Bluetooth service

This might be a result of missing location permissions. If you add neverForLocation attribute to the android:usesPermissionFlags for your BLUETOOTH_SCAN permission declaration, some BLE beacons are filtered from the scan results. See https://developer.android.com/develop/connectivity/bluetooth/bt-permissions#assert-never-for-location
